# Given $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, find the positive difference between the respective sums of their roots.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, roots

Here is another interesting math competition problem I found which I'd love to know how to do, especially given that I don't have much experience with products of sequences of terms. How would you solve this one?

> Define $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ as follows:
>
> $$f(x)=\prod_{i=0}^{2016}x^{i^{2017}}+\prod_{j=0}^{2017}(x^2+2016)^j$$
>
> $$g(x)=\prod_{i=0}^{2016}x^{2017^i}+\left(\prod_{j=0}^{2017}x^{2j}\right)2016x$$
>
> Find the positive difference between the respective sums of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$'s roots.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? What?

Comment: not really to be honest - i have little exposure to products of sequences but i just came across and wanted to see how it'd work out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay. First $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are polynomials. Next, the sum of roots in a polynomial is given by the coefficient of the $x^{n-1}$th term.
In $f(x)$ the highest power of $x$ is $\sum_{i=0}^{2016} i^{2017}$. Hence the sum of roots is  the coefficient of $x$ with power $\sum_{i=0}^{2016} i^{2017}-1$. In $f(x)$ all the other powers of $x$ come from the second term. The highest power of $x$ in that is $\sum_{j=0}^{2017}2j$ i.e 2017x2018. This is definitely not even close to  $\sum_{i=0}^{2016} i^{2017}-1$,the latter is bigger than $2016^{2017}$. Hence we conclude that there is no $x^{n-1}$ term which implies that the sum of roots in $f(x)$ is $0$. Applying the same argument to $g(x)$ we get the same result. Sum of roots in $g(x)$ is $0$. Hence the difference between the sum of their roots is $0$.

Comment: not to doubt your answer but is there any reason they might have asked specifically for a "positive" difference if the answer was 0?

Comment: Yea...I was also pondering about the same thing. Was the question an integer type where you have to fill the bubble?

Comment: it was open ended

Comment: Then I think they meant a positive difference to remove ambiguity. Suppose we got different roots then we subtract the smaller one from the bigger one.

Comment: right i was thinking the same thing, but here you didn't even get values - both of their roots are 0, so there was no reason to specify a positive difference. since this is a math competition question: perhaps to clarify it for those who didn't get the right roots? haha